# add acls in ldap for webseal using ivrgy_tool

Tags: ldap, webseal

I am trying to add acls specific to webseal in my newly configured openLDAP server.

I read there is a tool to do this named "ivrgy_tool"
I am new to LDAP and webseal. 
i am trying to run the command

> ivrgy_tool -h host=abkale2l -p 389 -D cn=Manager_dn -F add-acls
>   dc=maxcrc

but this command is again giving me manual page of the command

```
Manipulate Security Access Manager security info in the LDAP server.
usage:
    ivrgy_tool [options] command
options:
    -h host      LDAP server host name (required).
    -p port      LDAP server port number (if not specified, default LDAP port will be used.)
    -D dn        bind dn.
    -w password  bind password.
    -Z           Use SSL.
    -d           Debug (verbose) output.
    -K keyfile   SSL Key Database file.
    -P key_pw    keyfile password.
    -N key_name  private key name to use in keyfile.
    -S name      Security Master Principal Name.  (Default is "sec_master").
    -g name      Daemon type [acld-server or remote-acl-user]
    -s suffix    LDAP suffix under which to create the Management Domain (Default is "").
    -R           Remove from registry for 'uninstall' command (Default is FALSE).
    -v version   Indicates the data model version to use for 'install' command (Default is '6').
    -F           Force addition of ACLs even if domain is not defined on this server
                 (only valid for 'add-acls' command).
    -r rspfile   Fully qualified path and file name of the response file.

command:
    install <domain> <password>
    add-daemon <domain> <daemon> <password>
    del-daemon <domain> <daemon>
    list-daemon <domain>
    check-domain <domain>
    check-bind <dn> <password>
    check-db
    uninstall <domain>
    schema
    add-acls <domain>
```

I cant figure out where i am going wrong.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the problem was ... IBM Webseal does not support Open LDAP.
installed Java Direcctory server and worked perfectly.